# How can i convert json format?

Tags: javascript, json

The first one is the exact data format coming from sources and wanted to convert into second format. I cannot change the source, so wanted to change into required format.

I have gone through many posts which is related to my question, whereas I am not been able to find a proper solution for what I'm looking for.

**JSON Format**

```
"data": [
    {
        "title": "Dog",
        "channel_id": 1,
        "channel_image": "some channel image url",
        "playStationID": 1,
        "playStationGener": "Dog0",
        "playStationInfo": "blah blah",
        "playStationName": "ABC1",
        "playStationImage": "some image url",
        "isFavorite": "NO"
    },
    {
        "title": "Dog",
        "channel_id": 1,
        "channel_image": "some channel image url",
        "playStationID": 2,
        "playStationGener": "Dog1",
        "playStationInfo": "blah blah",
        "playStationName": "ABC2",
        "playStationImage": "some image url",
        "isFavorite": "NO"
    },
    {
        "title": "Cat",
        "channel_id": 2,
        "channel_image": "some channel image url",
        "playStationID": 4,
        "playStationGener": "Cat0",
        "playStationInfo": "blah blah",
        "playStationName": "XYZ1",
        "playStationImage": "some image url",
        "isFavorite": "NO"
    },
    {
        "title": "Cat",
        "channel_id": 2,
        "channel_image": "some channel image url",
        "playStationID": 4,
        "playStationGener": "Cat1",
        "playStationInfo": "blah blah",
        "playStationName": "ABC2",
        "playStationImage": "some image url",
        "isFavorite": "NO"
    }
]
```

**Required in this format**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Dog",
        "channel_id": 1,
        "channel_image": "some channel image url"
        "data": [
            {
                "playStationID": 1,
                "playStationGener": "Dog0",
                "playStationInfo": "blah blah",
                "playStationName": "ABC1",
                "playStationImage": "some image url",
                "isFavorite": "NO"
            },
            {
                "playStationID": 2,
                "playStationGener": "Dog1",
                "playStationInfo": "blah blah",
                "playStationName": "ABC2",
                "playStationImage": "some image url",
                "isFavorite": "NO"
            }
        ]
    },{
        "title": "Cat",
        "channel_id": 2,
        "channel_image": "some channel image url"
        "data": [
            {
                "playStationID": 4,
                "playStationGener": "Cat0",
                "playStationInfo": "blah blah",
                "playStationName": "XYZ1",
                "playStationImage": "some image url",
                "isFavorite": "NO"
            },
            {
                "playStationID": 4,
                "playStationGener": "Cat1",
                "playStationInfo": "blah blah",
                "playStationName": "ABC2",
                "playStationImage": "some image url",
                "isFavorite": "NO"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Please help!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: This sounds similar to a question posted [a few years back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575263/3971390). Worst-case scenario, you may just have to implement your own conversion routine.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish it using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const obj = {
  data: [{
      title: "Dog",
      channel_id: 1,
      channel_image: "some channel image url",
      playStationID: 1,
      playStationGener: "Dog0",
      playStationInfo: "blah blah",
      playStationName: "ABC1",
      playStationImage: "some image url",
      isFavorite: "NO",
    },
    {
      title: "Dog",
      channel_id: 1,
      channel_image: "some channel image url",
      playStationID: 2,
      playStationGener: "Dog1",
      playStationInfo: "blah blah",
      playStationName: "ABC2",
      playStationImage: "some image url",
      isFavorite: "NO",
    },
    {
      title: "Cat",
      channel_id: 2,
      channel_image: "some channel image url",
      playStationID: 4,
      playStationGener: "Cat0",
      playStationInfo: "blah blah",
      playStationName: "XYZ1",
      playStationImage: "some image url",
      isFavorite: "NO",
    },
    {
      title: "Cat",
      channel_id: 2,
      channel_image: "some channel image url",
      playStationID: 4,
      playStationGener: "Cat1",
      playStationInfo: "blah blah",
      playStationName: "ABC2",
      playStationImage: "some image url",
      isFavorite: "NO",
    },
  ],
};

const resObj = obj.data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const {
    title,
    channel_id,
    channel_image,
    ...rest
  } = curr;

  if (!acc[title]) {
    acc[title] = {
      title,
      channel_id,
      channel_image,
      data: [rest],
    };
  } else {
    acc[title]["data"].push(rest);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(resObj).map((x) => resObj[x]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: even better, you can use `...rest` in destructuring instead of extracting them and addng them to a new object

Comment: I was about to do this @FredStark . Thanks for suggestion