# How to parse data in a variety of data formats/structures?

Tags: validation, parsing, etl, data-modeling, data-ingestion

I'm terribly unfamiliar with the data engineering space, but here goes:

I have users that upload data in a variety of formats, that I want to convert to a single standard format. For example:

Source Format #1

```
{
  "firstName": "Bob",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "birthdate": "1990-01-01",
  "favoriteFood": "pizza",
  "favoriteDrink": "beer"
}
```

Source Format #2

```
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Bob",
    "last": "Smith"
  }
  "birthdate": {
    "year": "1990",
    "month": "01",
    "day": "01"
  }
  "favorites": {
    "food": "pizza",
    "drink": "beer"
  }
}
```

Target format:

```
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Bob",
    "last": "Smith"
  }
  "birthdate": "1990-01-01",
  "favorites": {
    "food": "pizza",
    "drink": "beer"
  }
}
```

And so on. There could be dozens or hundreds of different source formats that I want to convert from into some target format.

My first thought was to build a type of "format catalog" that I test each format against, and apply the transformation/map to the target format if there's a match. This sounds to me like a common enough problem that it's probably been addressed in some way, but I'm uncertain of what to even google for.

The only thing I've run into so far that *kind of* sounds right is [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/features/) (it talks about "automatic schema discovery"), but even that seems more directed at yanking data out of a variety of databases and ETLing them into a single database rather than reading raw data (from either data sent to an API endpoint or from a flat file on disk).

Features I'm interested in, in order of desirability:

1. If source data matches a known (or automatically discoverable) format, convert it to a target format.
2. Define required and optional fields. Example: if `favorite`s aren't present, still extract the other "known" fields
3. Be able to recognize different types of formats (such as JSON vs XML).

Edit: in case it matters, most of my existing code is written in Python, but this is a big enough use case that I could build a separate service in another language to handle.

Comment: You provided a couple of source formats in your question. What would the target format for these look like and would there be "mapping" to do this? Also is raw data source always in JSON format, or can it be delimited, etc.?

Comment: @vmachan Added a target format for completeness. 

For this use case the source is always in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but here is what I know\found out.

- Just like XML json also has schema: https://json-schema.org/
- If you have schema, you will have questions about transformation. Here is one: [json-schema: how to transform from one json-schema to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483654/json-schema-how-to-transform-from-one-json-schema-to-another)

I do not think you will find anything readymade that absolutely would match your requirements but I think you can get close enough.

Since this is a project not a quick question, I doubt you will get a *complete* answer with code.

HTH